SQL Injection query with UNION
I'm walking through some online training and I'm stuck in a place where I have to use SQL injection via a UNION query.
Here's the initial query:
SELECT *
FROM Transactions T
LEFT JOIN Accounts  as OA ON T.ownerAccountId = OA.Id
LEFT JOIN Accounts as FA ON T.foreignAccountId = FA.Id
WHERE T.ownerAccountId = 2
AND T.description LIKE '%ball%'

This will of course return a list of transactions that user has containing the keyword 'ball'.
I can modify the query to attempt an injection attack - in the 'search term' input box, I've added this:
ball%' OR 1==1   --
which now gives me the entire list of transactions, not just the one with the keyword.
Now, I'm trying to get the admin password from the Users table - so I've tried this in the 'search term' input box:
ball%' OR 1=1   UNION SELECT * FROM Users U  --
and uses this query:
SELECT *
FROM Transactions T
LEFT JOIN Accounts  as OA ON T.ownerAccountId = OA.Id
LEFT JOIN Accounts as FA ON T.foreignAccountId = FA.Id
WHERE T.ownerAccountId = 2
AND T.description LIKE '%ball%' OR 1=1   UNION SELECT * FROM Users U  --%'

what am I missing?
Here's other versions of the 'search term' input that I've tried:
ball%' OR 1=1 UNION SELECT * FROM Users U  '%

I did this originally since the code builds the query like this:
$query .= " AND T.description LIKE '%" . $searchTerm . "%'";

and I needed to bypass the second % - then found that I could just comment it out.

The SELECT statements in a UNION need to have the same number of columns returned, and the columns need to be a similar data type.  It's not clear from your question whether these requirements are being met with SELECT *

Are you only doing this through code injection, or do you have access to a database for testing? https://sqlfiddle.com/mysql/online-compiler?id=b9675cde-df5d-4775-99f1-0c5c0b34acb7

You don't need OR 1=1 when you use the UNION. The whole point of the exercise is that this is an alternative to that.

I do not have access to the database unfortunately.
I know there are 6 columns being returned from the initial query:
ID, From, To, Amount, Description, Date

"I do not have access to the database unfortunately" - I'm not asking about the database, just a database, such as that online REPL I linked to. I say that because you get to see all of the error messages than.

Are you able to do something like AND T.description LIKE '%ball%'; SELECT * FROM Users; in order to see the columns / data types available in Users?  You could then adjust your UNION and specify the column names to meet the UNION requirements instead of using SELECT *

If the joined table has less columns, you can also just use '' as a placeholder column

I did attempt this: AND T.description LIKE '%ball%'; SELECT * FROM Users;   and it threw an error

If you have 6 columns in the first query, you can have 6 columns in the second query by SELECT '', '', '', '', '', '' FROM Users U. Replace one or more of those '' with a valid column from Users that matches the type from the first query

i think if you register to portswigger and try learning SQL injection there, they have a whole lesson with lab  with full explanation on Union Based Attack:
https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection/union-attacks

@ChrisHaas MySQL is flexible about types, since everything can be cast to string.

@Barmar, since the OP tagged this with PHP, too, I was assuming there could be some additional finagling after the query was returned, so matching the types would be a way to get through that, too. That's also why I suggested '' instead of null, since, especially after the 8.1 update, PHP can freak out over null pretty easily.

In MySQL, the -- comment must be followed by at least one space or control character. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/ansi-diff-comments.html

@ChrisHaas - I've tried using the '',''..... in my SELECT statement without success.  I messaged the support team on this training site and they came back with "I'd suggest to use 1's instead of '' as fillers for your select statement.".

they are also telling me that I might not be getting through this check for $searchTerm:

if (!empty($searchTerm)) {
if (
strpos($searchTerm, 'UNION') !== false
|| strpos($searchTerm, 'union') !== false
|| strpos($searchTerm, '1 = 1') !== false
) {  return []; }
$query .= " AND T.description LIKE '%" . $searchTerm . "%'";
}
but I know I am when I use the OR 1=1 and then comment out any remaining part of the query
